# why am i getting this "the type of the expression must be an array type but resolved to string" in JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to do encryption but getting an error on the following code...
which says  "the type of the expression must be an array type but resolved to string".

```
String[] paragraph = new String[8];
        paragraph[0] = "Emirates Airline is one of the largest airlines in the world based in Dubai uae.\n"; 
        paragraph[1] = "The first flight of emirates airline landed in Karachi in 1998.\n ";
        paragraph[2] = "The biggest Airport terminal is in dubai international airport which is terminal 3.\n";
        paragraph[3] = "About more than hundred flight go through dubai international airport everyday.\n";
        paragraph[4] = "Dublin internationl airport is becoming a very busy airport in europe.\n";
        paragraph[5] = "Emirates airlines comes to dublin airport twice daily.\n";
        paragraph[6] = "In dublin airport a second runway is being built due heavy delays.\n";
        paragraph[7] = "A terminal 3 at dublin airport is being planned so it can accomodate more passengers.\n";



int n = random.nextInt(paragraph.length);
        System.out.println("--------Welcome To The Cipher Game-------");
        System.out.println("Select An Option Below To Start");

        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Normal Mode \n" + "Enter 2 for Test Mode\n");

        int playingmode = in.nextInt();
        playingmode(n, playingmode, paragraph, in);
        encryption(random, playingmode, paragraph);
    }


    String alphabets = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    for(int i=0; i<=paragraph.length(); i++) {
        char lower = Character.toLowerCase(paragraph.charAt(i));

        // myStr.indexOf("planet")
        int newalphabetposition = (alphabets.indexOf(lower) + random) % 26;
        //dna.charAt(i)
        paragraph[i] = (alphabets.charAt(newalphabetposition));
    }
```

Comment: Where is `paragraph` defined? It looks like a string, since you're calling `.charAt` on it, but your code is not a [mcve].

Comment: Please also tell us which line throws the error.

Comment: Error is coming on paragraph[ i ] the last line

Comment: You've got a couple issues. You show paragraph defined as an array, but where you are using it, you are treating it as a string. `.length()` and `charAt` are string methods. Have you shadowed your paragraph variable? ie declared it in two different locations.

Comment: how do I declare it in two different locations?

Comment: @Ahmed You haven't provided enough information. When you say `String[] paragraph` you declare it as an array. In the code snippet that follows it is a **String** that is why you can use `charAt` and `length()` but the compiler gives you an error when you use `paragraph[i]` some where you have `String paragraph` but you have not included it in your code.

Comment: I have edited more code.

Comment: Still not enough. Just include the whole class, sprinkling it out in tidbits is not working.